using jbutton to generate random integers
I need help with java random in generator code .It's a button that when entered generates 8 digit random numbers .
where to add the functionality in the button and how to add it should i declare in random in the function method or in the main method.
am stuck here because am using neteans swing
generateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        generateID();
    }
});


You need to write the code for method generateID()

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

How do I ask and answer homework questions?

Since this is for ID's, when creating your generateID() method, keep in mind on how to handle any duplicate ID generation. The chance of this happening on an 8 digit ID is higher than you might think.

As I understand,you are asking how to create a button that when pressed, generates a random 8-digit number. You should place the random number generating code in your generateID() function (or directly in the event listener). This is a simple implementation of your function that generates a number between 10000000 and 99999999 (inclusive) using Math.random():
private int generateID() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999999 - 10000000 + 1) + 10000000);
}


What they need this information for is not our concern. Stack overflow is a Q&A website, and i'm just trying to answer the question they asked.
